# How to Create specific timeframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have tracker data in that we store tracker number and arrive_timestamp.

```
+---------+-------------------+
|trackerno|              adate|
+---------+-------------------+
| 54046022|2019-03-01 18:00:00|
| 54030173|2019-03-01 17:45:00|
| 53451324|2019-03-01 17:50:00|
| 54002797|2019-03-01 18:30:00|
| 53471705|2019-03-01 17:59:00|
```

i want last 15 minutes of data between 17:44:59 to 17:59:59. I am using spark application .

expected output :

```
+---------+-------------------+
|trackerno|              adate|
+---------+-------------------+
| 54030173|2019-03-01 17:45:00|
| 53451324|2019-03-01 17:50:00|
| 53471705|2019-03-01 17:59:00|
```

Comment: i want this for every hours (0-24).

Comment: will window 15 minutes remain static every time. I mean will it always have a specific start and end time because 15 minutes window can fall at any time in between 0-24 hours of time. Please specify more details

Comment: Could you add what you have tried until now. Sounds like assignment question without any attempt on your part\.

Comment: v_df.distinct().withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(col("adate"))))
       .withColumn("Date",date_format(col("timestamp"),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
       .withColumn("time",date_format(col("timestamp"),"HH:mm:ss"))
       .withColumn("mydata",when(minute($"time").between(44,59),1).otherwise(0)).show()

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
  val df = Seq(
    (54046022, "2019-03-01 18:00:00"),
    (54030173, "2019-03-01 17:45:00"),
    (53451324, "2019-03-01 17:50:00"),
    (54002797, "2019-03-01 18:30:00"),
    (53471705, "2019-03-01 17:59:00")
  ).toDF("trackerno", "date")

  val tsDF = df.withColumn("ts", to_timestamp($"date"))

  val result = tsDF .
    select($"trackerno", $"date").
    where($"ts" >= to_timestamp(lit("2019-03-01 17:44:59")) &&
      $"ts" <= to_timestamp(lit("2019-03-01 17:59:59")))

  result.show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

your question was not much clear specially how you will measure a 15 minutes window start and end time. I am just answering it based on my little understanding.

creating a window with 15 minutes timeframe

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import window
grouped_window = df.groupBy(window("adate", "15 minutes"),"trackerno","adate").count()
```

This will lead you a results like this.

```
+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
|window                                    |trackerno|adate              |count|
+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
|[2019-03-01 17:45:00, 2019-03-01 18:00:00]|53451324 |2019-03-01 17:50:00|1    |
|[2019-03-01 18:30:00, 2019-03-01 18:45:00]|54002797 |2019-03-01 18:30:00|1    |
|[2019-03-01 17:45:00, 2019-03-01 18:00:00]|53471705 |2019-03-01 17:59:00|1    |
|[2019-03-01 18:00:00, 2019-03-01 18:15:00]|54046022 |2019-03-01 18:00:00|1    |
|[2019-03-01 17:45:00, 2019-03-01 18:00:00]|54030173 |2019-03-01 17:45:00|1    |
+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+-----+

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('window')

grouped_window.select('adate', 'trackerno', f.count('count').over(w).alias('dupeCount')).sort('adate')\
    .where('dupeCount > 1')\
    .drop('dupeCount')\
    .show()

+-------------------+---------+
|              adate|trackerno|
+-------------------+---------+
|2019-03-01 17:45:00| 54030173|
|2019-03-01 17:50:00| 53451324|
|2019-03-01 17:59:00| 53471705|
+-------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.where(minute($"ts")>=45)
```